# optimize subquery with count and order by field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to optimize below query which has a subquery from relation table and has a order by on subquery count data. Please see the below query:

```sql
SELECT table1.*, 
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM table2 
         WHERE table2.user_id=table1.id 
           AND table2.deleted = 0) AS table2_total
FROM table1
WHERE table1.parent_id = 0 
ORDER BY table2_total DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

This query works well but it stuck when table2 has more than 50K data. I have also tried to use left join instead of sub query but that is even more slower:

```sql
SELECT table1.*, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT table2.id) as table2_total 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id=table1.id 
                AND table2.deleted = 0
WHERE table1.parent_id = 0 
ORDER BY table2_total DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

table2 already has indexes on user_id and deleted column. Please see below table2 structure:
[image]

Is there any way to optimize this query in better way?

Comment: you need all column of table1 or some specific column are required ?

Comment: I need all columns from table1 :)

Comment: When you ask about optimization then you must provide precise server version, complete CREATE TABLE for all tables and EXPLAIN for the query to be optimized. At least.

Comment: I need to have all values from table1 and table2 may or may not have data. So inner join will not be suitable here.

Comment: Try to create index by `table2 (deleted, user_id)`. And just in case, create an index `table2 (user_id, deleted)`. Then check EXPLAIN - what of them will be used?

Comment: @Akina table2 already has this combined index for mentioned columns.

Comment: Show this. And EXPLAIN.

Comment: You don't need the `DISTINCT` keyword in the `LEFT JOIN` version *(either that, or you **do** need it in the sub-query version)*.  And the `LEFT JOIN` version is missing a `GROUP BY` clause *(such as `GROUP BY table1.id`)*

Comment: How many rows in table1?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, not a screenshot of the limited info that the UI provides.

Answer (score 1):

As written, it will go through the entirety of table1, and probe table2 that many times.

Add this composite index to table2:  `INDEX(user_id, deleted)` and remove the `INDEX(user_id)` that you currently seem to have.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add index to the column  table2.deleted And table1.parent_id. The index is going to impact the performance of the insert .

Comment: *The index is going to impact the performance of the insert .* (1) The query type is not INSERT. (2) Index always decreases INSERT performance.

Comment: I know but just telling that there is an  impact of  using index on insert  performance.